# Testing my ios app in device

Tags: ios, xcode5

The version of iOS on my iPad is 8.0.2 (12A405) and my mac pc SDKs iOS version 7.1 (11D167). 
I am not able to test my ios app in my ipad. Apple is asking me to update to the latest sdk version. If I upgrade my pc to latest sdk which is xcode 6 sdk 8.0 will my app run into issue. Please provide me guidance. Currently I using xcode 5.

Comment: you better create an ipa file then, install it in device and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one option you have. Generate an iPA file and install into your device and run it. Or else you have to update your device to latest sdk.

Comment: Thanks gunas & vishnu I was able to do it with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Update the SDK, so you can test your app on the iPad. This will *probably not* cause issues with your app. I also found no issues with this after searching Google and Stack Overflow.
2. Do not update the SDK, but you won't be able to test your app on the device.

**Choose option 1, because you need to test the app.**